# In Farcry 3 does taking outpost affect the number of wild animals?

Tags: far-cry-3

In Farcry 3 it seems like at the start of the game, when there are a lot of enemy outposts, I seem to encounter more wild animals.

Do outpost affect the chance to encounter animals or do I just notice it more when I have crappy weapons?

[image: Ouch]

It seems like the second island has far fewer wild animals... Again, maybe that's just the weapons I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this doesn't happen to me. I've captured all outposts, save AM12 and I meet tons of wild animals, probably more than I met at the start of the game.

Also, I own two signature weapons, so that doesn't really affect their numbers either.

Answer (score 0):

the number of captured outposts doesn't affect the amount of wild animals you encounter.

one of the outposts i have captured tends to have tigers around it a lot

another has komodo dragons all around it.

as i progressed and got more outposts, the number of spawns has not changed.

so i don't believe so.